# Is it allowed in islam to do something haram if it benefits humanity?

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-philosophy

For example :

Alcohol is haram is islam but it help us in many ways like

Industrial methylated spirits, Use of ethanol as a fuel, Ethanol as a solvent, Methanol as a fuel, Methanol as an industrial feedstock.

These are the different usage of alcohol that doesn't require drinking.

But to obtain these kinds of alcohol we need to do research and learn about alcohol.

Is it allowed to do such kinds or research in islam.

Music is haram in islam. But is a therapy called [music therapy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_therapy),that can help us to cure many diseases.

**So I am asking is it allowed to do things that are forbidden in islam if they are for greater good and will benefit humanity alot**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If God teaches us that something is haram, there's a reason behind it and it cannot be good for humanity to do it.

If something is good for humanity, it should not be haram because God will not forbid to do good.

If we see a conflict between a commandment and what we feel is beneficial to humanity, there may be several reasons:

- We think that it's good but it isn't.
- We think that it's haram but it isn't.

Your example of industrial alcohol is an evident example for something you considered haram but it isn't. In fact, not alcohol is haram but drinking alcohol is. If a commandment is taken too short and too general, one may avoid something although it is not forbidden and not even discouraged but good.

Your example of music therapy is more complex. At first, saying that music is haram is again too wide a generalization of the hadith that are critical to music because there are other hadith that imply that music is not haram in general. Thus, a more detailed study is necessary which will also end up in an evaluation as to why a commandment has been given and whether this reason is given. Traditional fiqh is very prudent on such reasoning and prefers to judge on written words but in many questions still has to interpret them with reason.

It would be worth studying this subject in detail as a separate question. Scholars have different opinions on this topic.

There's also a possibility that a falsely acknowledged or mutilated hadith is taken as a commandment thus leading to a commandment God has not given. This is very difficult because in our days this can hardly be verified. Cases where a commandment is only based on one hadith are often solved declaring it undesirable but not strictly haram. By this, it cannot completely be excluded that something good is declared forbidden or undesirable.

Answer (score -1):

The meaning of haram is something that brings you bad deeds. So any action that brings you bad deeds is haram.

Allah says "Read" (Surat Al-‘Alaq, verse 1). Reading is part of a research.

The usage of alcohol is only prohibited in food, otherwise it can be used however you want (because it does not bring bad deeds).

If it’s for the good of humanity that you’re taking into consideration, it must have no bad effects (like getting drunk, causing harm or intoxication).

Music therapy has no bad effects and does not bring bad deeds (it also is a way to heal someone) so it’s halal.

Comment: I agree except on the last one. Music is haram.